# Auto scrolling to the end of NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextview

I have a NSTextView on which I am appending console logs. I have implemented this UI in XIB file with scroll views. When my application appends the console logs in the text view, I want the scroll bar to automatically go to the end of the textview. I could not find any property in XIB editor. Any idea how can I achieve this?

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet NSTextView *logTextView;

    [[self.logTextView textStorage] beginEditing];
    [[[self.logTextView textStorage] mutableString] appendString:iData];
    [[[self.logTextView textStorage] mutableString] appendString:@"\n"];
    [[self.logTextView textStorage] endEditing];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your goal by using `-[NSText scrollRangeToVisible:]` after appending your string. (`NSTextView` is a subclass of `NSText`.)

Sorry, but that's the only way. As you observed, there's no IB check box that effects this particular behavior.

Apropos of nothing, you could replace your two `-[NSMutableString appendString:]` calls with one `-[NSMutableString appendFormat:]` call.