# how to get a textview to autoscroll down when theres a new line

Tags: swift, cocoa

in swift 4.0 for cocoa applications

how do you get a textview to autoscroll down when theres a new line
of text added into it?

is there a built in function for this?

i can't seem to find a way to do this.

```
chatplace.scroll(<#T##point: NSPoint##NSPoint#>)
```

Comment: `NSTextView` or `UITextView`?

Comment: its  NSTextView!

Comment: Did you try [Auto scrolling to the end of NSTextView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16465365/4244136)?

Answer (score -1):

Here's a simple example that works:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var count = 0
    var timer:Timer?
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        textView.isScrollEnabled = true
        textView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        timer = Timer(timeInterval: 0.125, repeats: true, block: { (timer) in
            self.count += 1
            self.textView.text.append("\n\(self.count) This is another line")
        })
        if let timer = timer {
            RunLoop.current.add(timer, forMode: .commonModes)
        }
    }
}
```

The result:

[image: output]

If you want to scroll programmatically this should do it:

```
func scrollToEnd(_ someTextView:UITextView) {
    let bottom = NSMakeRange(someTextView.text.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8)-1, 1)
    someTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(bottom)
}
```